# Action Bar Items (Action Items) are not showing in android.

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbaractivity

I have two menu items in **`menu/contacts_menu.xml`** as :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/pm_action_search"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        android:title="@string/action_search"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/show_online"
        android:icon="@drawable/online_icon"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="Show Online"/>

   </menu>
```

Where , in my **`Fragment`** :

```
    @Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.contacts_menu, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.show_online) {
        // DO SOMETHING
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

I have done the same procedure in my others apps, and action items are showing. But in my current app, they are not showing. only if i press the menu button, action items are showing only with text. i want to show the icons on my action bar.

Comment: Try from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24264278/actionbar-is-not-displaying-icons-in-android/24264519#24264519

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are using appcompat library? Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:appcompat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/pm_action_search"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
        appcompat:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
        android:title="@string/action_search" />
    <item

        android:id="@+id/show_online"
        android:icon="@drawable/online_icon"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        appcompat:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Show Online" />

</menu>
```

This should definitely work, but for simplicity you can also try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:appcompat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/pm_action_search"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        appcompat:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
        android:title="@string/action_search" />
    <item

        android:id="@+id/show_online"
        android:icon="@drawable/online_icon"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        appcompat:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Show Online" />

</menu>
```